# MongoDB Download for Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: mongodb, download, windows-10

I'm trying to download MongoDB and I'm running Windows 10 64bit. All of the versions for download say either Windows Server 2008 64bit, or Windows Vista 32bit. Is it fine to just get one of the Windows Server 2008 versions, or is there just no support for Windows 10? Am I missing some sort of equivalence?

[Current Downloads Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14l2s.png)

Comment: Windows Server 2008 64bit **and later**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The windows server 2008 64 bit version runs fine under Windows 10 x64.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

Answer (score 10):

Uncheck "Install MongoDB Compass" and try again. worked for me